# Jquery context not returning existing element from ajax request

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I'm calling via an AJAX $.get(...) the same page that would be called if the form would be submitted and i do get valid results returned, but strangely, if i do:

```
$('#searchResultsWrapper').html($('#searchResultsWrapper', data).html());
```

It doesn't find the #searchResultsWrapper... I've confirmed it exists and works but i just can seem to get it to work at all. I do the exact same thing with the result message of the search and it works fine:

```
$('#searchMessage').html($('#searchMessage', data).html());
```

Is there a limit to the amount of data i can search into when passing "data" into the context of the selector?

Comment: you have to try .on method once it helps you better

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Element is there but you can't access it with context? That seem like a *"element is the root of data"* case.

If the element is indeed the root of `data`, you'll need to use `filter` :

```
$(data).filter('#searchMessage');
```

Of you can also make a global search like that :

```
$('<div>').append(data).find('#searchMessage');
```

Comment: Nope, i'm loading in "data" all of the page, not just a portion of it, i'll try the find method though, might work

Comment: @MathieuDumoulin Yeah, maybe parsing the HTML may be a good idea. But i'm pretty sure using data as context should parse it...

Comment: Yay, i got it work using the filter method. Code now looks like: $('#searchResultsWrapper').html($(data).filter('#searchResultsWrapper')); and it works fine, thanks karl